# How to shift one column, based on values from another column?

Tags: python, machine-learning, indexing

I have a data frame like this:

[image: What I have]

I want to make column "flag" which will spot the change in "value" column FOR EACH RB individualy and only if the value increases, and put it 1 one month before change when the value increases, but only if that month before has the same RB, as month of the change. So shift cant help, I think.
[image: First column I want to add]

Also want to make simillar column, but when value increases for one RB, then I put 1 in the month before ( as column above ), 2 months before and 3 months beofre, the rule stays the same 1 only "shift" for those 3 months if month of the change and all those 3 months have same RB.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do, what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/01/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/02/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/03/2020", "value": 4},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/04/2020", "value": 6},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/05/2020", "value": 6},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/06/2020", "value": 6},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/07/2020", "value": 6},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/08/2020", "value": 7},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/01/2020", "value": 3},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/02/2020", "value": 3},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/03/2020", "value": 4},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/04/2020", "value": 4},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/05/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/06/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/07/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/08/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/01/2020", "value": 18},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/02/2020", "value": 18},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/03/2020", "value": 17},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/04/2020", "value": 11},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/05/2020", "value": 13},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/06/2020", "value": 13},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/07/2020", "value": 13},
    {"rb": 111, "date": "01/08/2020", "value": 13},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/01/2020", "value": 14},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/02/2020", "value": 14},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/03/2020", "value": 17},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/04/2020", "value": 17},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/05/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/06/2020", "value": 5},
    {"rb": 112, "date": "01/07/2020", "value": 5}
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df["flag"] = 0
for index in range(len(df) - 1):
    df.loc[index, "flag"] = int(df.loc[index, "rb"] == df.loc[index + 1, "rb"] and
                                df.loc[index, "value"] < df.loc[index + 1, "value"])

df["flag_3m"] = 0
for index in range(len(df)):
    try:
        df.loc[index, "flag_3m"] = int(df.loc[index, "flag_3m"] != 1 and
           ((df.loc[index, "value"] < df.loc[index + 1, "value"] and df.loc[index, "rb"] == df.loc[index + 1, "rb"]) or
           (df.loc[index + 1, "value"] < df.loc[index + 2, "value"] and df.loc[index, "rb"] == df.loc[index + 2, "rb"]) or
           (df.loc[index + 2, "value"] < df.loc[index + 3, "value"] and df.loc[index, "rb"] == df.loc[index + 3, "rb"])))
    except:
        # Dirty way ;)
        pass

print(df)
```

PS: Maybe it is easier to first `groupby` by rb and then check the data, but this should work, too.

Comment: Thank you for you solution and if works just fine for some caese, but in another cases where value decreases flag 3m stays 0, and it sholud be 1.

Comment: I do not read anything about decreasing in your question, only increasing. Please specify, when it should write the 1 and where it failed

Comment: The thing is, when it decreases, before it increases, it erases 1 eather for 2 months ago, or 3 months ago. Try you code with this values 18,18,17,11,13,13,13,13,14,14,17,17,5,5,5 and watch what happens with "flag 3m" column, it doesn't return thre times 1, for every 1 in flag column.

Comment: I fixed the two lines before `except`, there was a mistake in the comparison

Comment: Chek out flag_3m, for the last value 1 in flag, there is only two 1, instead of three

Comment: yeah, but this should be correct, because the 3rd 1 would be on an other rb, or am I wrong?

Comment: Now is perfect, you are right it was other rb, thank you.